# Geolocation plugin permission alert on iPhone with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Two time alert show first alert is correct but second alert generate with string with would like to use your current location.

How do you change the string on the alert saying:
/var/mobile/Applications/157EB70D-4AA7-826E-690F0CBE0F/appname.app/www/index.html

Someone having an idea?

Comment: did you install the geolocation plugin? did you include the cordova.js file in your index.html?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code on device ready:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}

function onSuccess(position) {
   //Retrieve latitude as: alert(position.coords.latitude);
   //Retrieve longitude as: alert(position.coords.longitude);
}

function onError(error) {
   console.log('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```